# Does it make sense to add a Next.js app to a node project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, backend

I have an API written with Node and Typescript with PostgreSQL as the DB. I am deciding if I should go with React or Next. Since I already have the endpoints written, does it add any value to use Next? Or should I just go with React?

What kind of advantages would using Next.js over React have when it comes to handling api/server calls?

Wondering what a more experienced dev has to say on the topic.

Note: I have no experience with Next. I am well versed with React.

Comment: First, having the endpoints written makes no difference to your decision. The question is whether you want to move to a framework and all that means and move away from a library and the flexibility that offers. Are you ready to do things to Next way and not your way?

Comment: The comment about the endpoints is because you can simply implement client side fetch: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side - it works the way you expect React to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `Next.js` over only `React` is that Next.js is built on-top of React. It also provides a much better, seamless and simpler implementation SSR (Server-Side-Rendering) than even just `React 18` provides. If you used `Next.js` you could essentially use it as client-side only if you wanted, but I highly recommend diving right into Next.js 13 since it's backwards compatible with v12 due to major changes - which I find really nice.

Check out the [Next.js 13 Beta Docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs) if you're okay with working in an environment where some of the things may change.

Check out the [Next.js 12 Stable Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs) if you need something rock-solid. It still provides SSR and is built on-top of React. It's a difference of `pages` vs `app` folder.

I find that once I switched to Next.js I don't need to go back to just React alone. You can also still fetch your existing Node.js API backend easily through Next.js directly from your `Client components` (React). Your `Server components` are still in JSX they just have some limitations like no accessibility to `Context` or `State`.

You'll also find SEO is much easier to deal with in a Next.js app than a React app.